# I'm able to change the image of a card when it is being hovered over. But how do I do this for a large number of cards with different images

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is an html sample for one card:

```
        <div class="col s4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
              <img src="img/forZane/Bowl_Andrew (1).jpg" onmouseover="hover(this);" onmouseout="unhover(this);">
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
              <h4 class="md-font">ceramic one.</h4>
              <p class="md-font">$50.</p>
            </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
```

and this is the javascript that i'm using:

```
  element.setAttribute('src', 'img/forZane/Bowl_Andrew (2).jpg');
}

function unhover(element) {
  element.setAttribute('src', 'img/forZane/Bowl_Andrew (1).jpg');
}
```

I can't figure out how to apply this function/hover technique to different cards with different images.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add custom [`data-*`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp) attributes to your `img` tags, so that your `hover`/`unhover` functions can change the image in each case.

Take this for example:

```js
function hover(element) {
  element.setAttribute('src', element.getAttribute('data-hover'));
}
function unhover(element) {
  element.setAttribute('src', element.getAttribute('data-unhover'));
}
```

```html
<div class="col s4">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">
      <img src="img (1).jpg" data-hover="img (2).jpg" data-unhover="img (1).jpg" onmouseover="hover(this);" onmouseout="unhover(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <h4 class="md-font">ceramic one.</h4>
      <p class="md-font">$50.</p>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col s4">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">
      <img src="img (1).jpg" data-hover="img (2).jpg" data-unhover="img (1).jpg" onmouseover="hover(this);" onmouseout="unhover(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <h4 class="md-font">ceramic one.</h4>
      <p class="md-font">$50.</p>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

If your filenames are indeed in a consistent format, and all you need to do is switch between filenames ending in "(1)" and "(2)", consider the following alternative.

Here, we remove the `data-*` attributes, and instead do a replacement of the `src` attribute.

```js
function hover(element) {
  element.setAttribute('src', element.getAttribute('src').replace('(1)', '(2)'));
}
function unhover(element) {
  element.setAttribute('src', element.getAttribute('src').replace('(2)', '(1)'));
}
```

```html
<div class="col s4">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">
      <img src="img (1).jpg" onmouseover="hover(this);" onmouseout="unhover(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <h4 class="md-font">ceramic one.</h4>
      <p class="md-font">$50.</p>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col s4">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">
      <img src="img (1).jpg" onmouseover="hover(this);" onmouseout="unhover(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <h4 class="md-font">ceramic one.</h4>
      <p class="md-font">$50.</p>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for multiple images by introducing a new parameter to your functions that set the image url to that value:

```js
function hover(element, url)
  element.setAttribute('src', url);
}

function unhover(element, url) {
  element.setAttribute('src', url);
}
```

```html
  <div class="col s4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="img/forZane/Bowl_Andrew (1).jpg" onmouseover="hover(this, 'img/forZane/Bowl_Andrew (2).jpg');" onmouseout="unhover(this, 'img/forZane/Bowl_Andrew (1).jpg');">
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <h4 class="md-font">ceramic one.</h4>
        <p class="md-font">$50.</p>
      </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="img/AnotherImage.jpg" onmouseover="hover(this, 'img/AnotherImageHover.jpg');" onmouseout="unhover(this, 'img/AnotherImage.jpg');">
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <h4 class="md-font">wodden one.</h4>
        <p class="md-font">$70.</p>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

That way, you can have the same effect among multiple images.